# How can I read man pages in my native language?

Tags: documentation, contributing, translation, manpage

How can I read man pages in my mother tongue?

I'd also like to contribute some translations.

- Where should I go?
- Is there a community supported by
  Canonical?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Install the package named `language-pack-<two letter language code>`
   e.g. `sudo apt-get install language-pack-es` for Spanish
2. Install the package named `manpages-<two letter language code>`
   e.g. `apt-get install manpages-es` for Spanish man pages.
3. Set your `LANG` environment variable to `<language>_<country>.<encoding>`,
   e.g. `LANG=es_ES.UTF-8`
4. Run `man`

[List of language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I've tried, but there is no *ko* yet. *ko* is korean. Who did translate your language? Canonical?

Comment: You're right, it looks like Korean hasn't been supported since 2005.  Try asking here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/manpages-ko/+addquestion or join up to contribute here: https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+translations

Answer (score 3):

First part of question already answered. This will answer second part of question.

Look at this page and locate you language and open the page  for your language team from the link.

https://translations.launchpad.net/+groups/ubuntu-translators

If your language is not  in the list refer
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/KnowledgeBase/StartingTeam 
on how to start one team

These are translated by community of translation volunteers.