# How do I get started with Translations?

Tags: internationalization, translation

My friend and i would like to translate Ubuntu. where should we start? where to find translation tools?

Comment: Also, see the answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/25089/how-can-i-read-manpages-in-my-mother-tongue/25109#25109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Translations](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations) page in the Ubuntu Wiki explains the process very well.

Comment: While that page is an excellent resource and no answer would be complete without recommending it, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/), and get an account (there's a [Creating an account](https://launchpad.net/+login) link in the "Get started" section).

Then go to the [translations](https://translations.launchpad.net/) area (there's also a link from the home page).

Answer (score -3):

You also read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations

Cheers ;)