# How to translate Ubuntu One web UI?

Tags: ubuntu-one, translation

I would like to know if it is currently or will be possible to translate the Ubuntu One web UI, because I know people, and I'm sure there are lot of them, who don't understand any English words, and so don't use it. 
I really that think it is very important to make it translatable, to have it used by the most people possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Translations?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26999/how-do-i-get-started-with-translations)

Comment: Not an exact dupe as the U1 web UI may not follow the traditional translations paths. IMO this question should stay open until translations are possible.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, you can't translate the web ui. There's 2 reasons for this:

- There's a lot of actual technical work that needs to be done, and it hasn't been a priority so far
- Since we sell plans, the translations are a sensitive issue since it can lead to fraud. We would need some oversight over the translations, and we don't have the resources to do this for many languages

I do understand, though, the importance of internationalisation, and it comes up frequently in our discussions so I'm sure we'll eventually manage to carve out the time and budget to kick it off.

Comment: Do you still have no plans for that (I know it's difficult, but lot of people would like that I'm sure) ?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there are still no plans to translate the website.