# Linux man pages in different languages

Tags: command-line, language-support, manpage

My Ubuntu 18.04 is set to Spanish:

[image]

But man pages are displayed in English, not according to the configuration (Spanish).

```
$ man cp | head -n4
CP(1)                            User Commands                       CP(1)

NAME
   cp - copy files and directories
```

The following is what I tried to get man page in Spanish:

```
$ LANG=es_ES.utf8 man cp   # result is in English
$ LANGUAGE=es_ES:es man cp # result is in English
$ man -Les cp              # result is in English
$ man --locale=es cp       # result is in English
```

To verify es_ES is correctly installed:

```
$ locale -a | grep es_ES
es_ES.utf8
```

To verify the man pages for Spanish is installed:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep language-pack-es
ii  language-pack-es                           1:18.04+20180712                             
all          translation updates for language Spanish; Castilian
ii  language-pack-es-base                      1:18.04+20180712                             
all          translations for language Spanish; Castilian
```

To force re-creating man pages

```
$ sudo mandb -c
```

After all of these, try the first 3 commands and none of them produces man pages in Spanish.

---

References:

None of the solutions here work:

[How can I read man pages in my native language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25089/how-can-i-read-man-pages-in-my-native-language)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283660/how-to-change-the-language-for-man-command
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43384/localization-of-man-pages-on-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man` takes the `-L` option as well as environment variables as `$LC_MESSAGES` and `$LANG` into account, but it can’t display `man` pages in a language they are not (yet?) translated to. Using `find` we can easily get a list of available translations, e.g. for `cp`:

```
$ find /usr/share/man -name "cp.*"
/usr/share/man/man1/cp.1.gz
```

That means there’s only one version, not located in any of the language subdirectories, that’s the default English one. Let’s take a look at results for the `man` command:

```
$ find /usr/share/man -name "man.*"
/usr/share/man/nl/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/sv/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/sr/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/es/man1/man.1.gz
…
```

The list goes on and shows the available languages, `es` being one of them. You can use one of

```
LANGUAGE=es_ES.utf8 man man
man -L es_ES.utf8 man
man -Les man
```

to display it. In fact, if the locale environment variables in your terminal are set accordingly `man` will always display `man` pages in Spanish and only fall back to English if a Spanish translation is not available, like you experienced with `man cp`. To set this up, run `locale` and see if `$LANGUAGE` is set to `es_ES.utf8`. If it’s not, add a line `LANGUAGE=es_ES.utf8` to your `~/.bashrc` or define an alias like `alias man='man -Les'`.

Catering to [waltinators answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113659/507051) there may be additional packages available holding translations, you can take a look at their file lists on https://packages.ubuntu.com or with e.g. `apt-file list manpages-es`. [`manpages-es`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/manpages-es/filelist) and [`manpages-es-extra`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/manpages-es-extra/filelist) look promising, however none of them contains a `man` page for the `cp` command.

Answer (score 3):

Since not everybody has disk space for every-language `man` pages, and since the `LANG` variable doesn't cause translation, you probably need to install one or more packages:

```
$ apt-cache search Spanish|grep man
aptitude-doc-es - Spanish manual for aptitude, a terminal-based package manager
drascula-german - classic 2D point and click adventure game -- German version
drgeo-doc - Dr. Geo online user manual
manpages-es - Spanish man pages
manpages-es-extra - Spanish extra manpages
apertium-es-ro - Apertium translation data for the Spanish-Romanian pair
```